# Store javascript variable into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Is it possible to store variables into arrays? What is the correct way of doing it? I can't seem to be able to store it in this way.

```
var fxVal = '<?php echo $fxVal;?>';
var equitiesVal = '<?php echo $equitiesVal;?>';
var boVal = '<?php echo $boVal;?>';
var balance = '<?php echo $account_balance;?>';

var myData = [fxVal,equitiesVal,boVal,balance];
```

Comment: marray = new Array("Marry", "Christmas", "Mr.", "Array");

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are several ways to do it:

```
var array1 = [var1, var2, var3, var4];
var array2 = new Array(var1, var2, var3, var4);
```

or

```
var array3 = new Array;

array3.push(var1);
array3.push(var2);
array3.push(var3);
array3.push(var4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into JSON as data format.

```
var data = <?= json_encode([$fxVal, $equitiesVal, $boVal, $account_balance]); ?>;
```

When you want to send or receive more data consider using AJAX.